# Formulario básico en React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript

Teniendo un formulario del estilo:

```
constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
        value1: '',
        value2: '',
        value3: '',
        value4: ''
    }
}

render(){
    <div>
        <input type="text" value={this.state.value1}/>
        <input type="text" value={this.state.value2}/>
        <input type="text" value={this.state.value3}/>
        <input type="text" value={this.state.value4}/>
        <button type="submit"/>
    </div>
}
```

¿Existe alguna manera de no realizar una funcion onChange por cada celda "input" para que me permita realizar cambios en el valor? Es decir, una funcion general que me permita cambiar todos los datos, y al realizar el submit realizar el guardado de esos datos. En conclusión, un formulario básico con su funcionalidad en React.

Comment: Mira por acá http://stackoverflow.com/a/25187443/154762

Comment: puedes crear una unica  funcion handler para todos los input si lo desea

Answer (score 2):

si si puede usar un unico metodo para todos los textbox

```
setField (e) {
 this.setState({[e.target.name]: e.target.value})
}
```

y usarlo asi

```
<input type="text"
    onChange={(e)=>this.setField(e)}
    name="saluditos"
   />

  <input type="text"
   onChange={(e)=>this.setField(e)}
   name="direccion"
   />
```

name seria obligatorio en cada textbox

> revise la documentacion de react js con es6 https://babeljs.io/blog/2015/06/07/react-on-es6-plus para que este mas informado

Pero tenga en cuenta y piense en mas adelante que cada textbox puede variar, no todos van a tener de entreda los mismos datos, de ser asi una funcion para manejar cada textbox de manera individual seria mas adecuado

por si tiene duda y como detalle extra usted puede ver informacion sombre el evento target ===> [evento target](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_target.asp)

Answer (score 1):

Una forma de lograrlo siguiendo fielmente [la documentación de React](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#handling-multiple-inputs) 
 (sección Handling Multiple Inputs) sería:

```
handleInputChange(event) {
  const name = event.target.name;
  const value = event.target.value;

  this.setState({
    [name]: value,
  });
}

.
.
.

<div>
  <input type="text" value={this.state.value1} onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
  <input type="text" value={this.state.value2} onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
  <input type="text" value={this.state.value3} onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
  <input type="text" value={this.state.value4} onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
  <button type="submit"/>
</div>
```

La versión de Sergio Romero es similar. No es necesario en este caso declarar una arrow function en el onChange.

La ventaja de tener separados las funciones que cambian el estado con cada cambio de texto en los input es que puedes hacer validaciones específicas (para cada campo). También puede darse el caso en que necesites realizar un llamado a un servicio REST cuando haya un cambio en un input (obviando el uso de Redux y otro tipo de herramientas para realizar los llamados asíncronos y esperar a que se resuelvan para actualizar el estado) como por ejemplo una barra de búsqueda que haga consultas a dicho servicio.

Answer (score 1):

Para mejorar el rendimiento es mejor evitar usar `bind` y las `arrow functions` en el render, lo [recomendable](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/handling-events.html) es hacerlo en el constructor.

Un ejemplo simple de como podría ser:

```
export default class Form extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: '',
      email: ''
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
  }
  handleChange (e) {
    const name = e.target.name;
    const value = e.target.value;
    this.setState({
      [name]: value
    })
  };
  render () {
    return (
      <form>
        <input
          type='text'
          name='name'
          value={this.state.name}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
        />
        <input
          type='text'
          name='email'
          value={this.state.email}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
        />
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes añadir esa función "general" en el evento onSumit del formulario: **onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}** y en esa función modificar el state con **this.setState(...)** y realizar las acciones que quieras.

Comment: Sí, pero cada celda necesita un método onChange para que pueda realizar cambios en ella si no me equivoco. A eso es lo que me refiero.

Comment: No le asignes un valor this.state... a los _inputs_ y podrás editarlos libremente. Luego en la funcion **onSubmit** recupera los valores con **document.querySelector("xxx").value** y asigna el estado

Answer (score 0):

Hechale un vistazo a [Uncontrolled Components](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/uncontrolled-components.html), básicamente lo que propone es que el DOM se haga responsable de gestionar el estado de los inputs, sin embargo puede darse el caso de que tu componente tenga dos fuentes de la verdad, el state y el DOM, eso puede conllevar a que tu componente llegue a estar en un estado inconsistente y por ende provoque comportamientos impredecibles, algo difícil de detectar y debuggear en lenguajes funcionales, por lo que ahorrarte el código para sincronizar los valores del input con el State viene a un alto precio, es recomendable hacer esto en casos excepcionales como cuando íntegras una librería no-react en un componente react por ejemplo.